# Inject RedeliveryPolicy to Spring boot ActiveMQ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, jms, activemq-classic

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-activemq` with `PoolFactory`. Everything works great and it's easy to configure via `application.yaml`, but I cannot find correct way to inject my custom `RedeliveryPolicy`. So the question is how can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The re-delivery policy can be set on the connection factory. As the connection factory is configured automatically by spring boot, you can add a method to set it.

```
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class Foo
{
    @Bean
    public InitializingBean connectionFactory(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
    {
        return () ->
        {
            RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
            // configure redelivery policy
            connectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);
        };
    }
}
```

**Update**

As stated in one reply, the above solution works well when the following configuration is not set `spring.activemq.pool.enabled = true`.

When using a pooled connection factory, Spring Boot auto-configures a `org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory` instead of `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory`. This configuration happens here: `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactoryConfiguration.PooledConnectionFactoryConfiguration#pooledJmsConnectionFactory` in the following line:

```
PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory(new ActiveMQConnectionFactoryFactory(properties,factoryCustomizers.getIfAvailable()).createConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.class));
```

In order to make this work you have two options:

1. Use the common parent for `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` and `PooledConnectionFactory` when injecting the bean, which is `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory`, and use instance-of and casting to set the redelivery policy.

   ```
       @Bean
       public InitializingBean connectionFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

           if (connectionFactory instanceof ActiveMQConnectionFactory) {
               return configureRedeliveryPolicy((ActiveMQConnectionFactory) connectionFactory);

           } else if (connectionFactory instanceof PooledConnectionFactory) {
               final PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = (PooledConnectionFactory) connectionFactory;
               if (pooledConnectionFactory.getConnectionFactory() instanceof ActiveMQConnectionFactory) {
                   return configureRedeliveryPolicy((ActiveMQConnectionFactory) pooledConnectionFactory.getConnectionFactory());
               }
           }
           // ...
       }
   ```
2. Have two different custom initialization scenarios for each bean type, which is basically the same as 1, but you're leveraging `ConditionalOnBean` instead of checking for the connectionFactory class type.

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class Foo {
       @Bean
       @ConditionalOnBean(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.class)
       public InitializingBean connectionFactory(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
           return configureRedeliveryPolicy(connectionFactory);
       }

       @Bean
       @ConditionalOnBean(PooledConnectionFactory.class)
       public InitializingBean pooledConnectionFactory(PooledConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
           if (connectionFactory.getConnectionFactory() instanceof ActiveMQConnectionFactory) {
               return configureRedeliveryPolicy((ActiveMQConnectionFactory) connectionFactory.getConnectionFactory());
           } else return () -> {
               // do something else
           };
       }

       private InitializingBean configureRedeliveryPolicy(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
           return () ->
           {
               RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
               // configure redelivery policy
               connectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);
           };
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Works very well as long as I do not use org.apache.activemq.PoolesConnectionFactory by setting spring.activemq.pool.enabled = true. Then it fails with NoSuchBeanDefinitionException regarding the ActiveMQConnectionFactory. Any idea, how I could configure redelivery in Spring when using pooling?

Comment: @micgn I've updated the response to cover the scenario you have described. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 10):

I have tried the answer from @Iulian Rosca but it does not work for latest version of spring-boot-starter-activemq (I'm using version 2.2.0.RELEASE).

Spring provides many other implementation classes for `ConnectionFactory`, such as `CachingConnectionFactory`, `JmsPooledConnectionFactory`,... and they are not inherited to each others. Therefore, the above solution need to refactor with many class type.

I discover Spring provide a functional interface `ActiveMQConnectionFactoryCustomizer`, which will be injected when create ActiveMQ Connection Factory, whichever class no matter. It will customize connection factory class, you can set any properties, not only redelivery policy.

Here is my sample code:

```java
@Configuration
public class RedeliveryCofiguration {

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactoryCustomizer configureRedeliveryPolicy() {
        return connectionFactory ->
        {
            RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
            // configure redelivery policy
            connectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);
        };
    }
}
```